# Visualforce render as pdf not displaying correct Devnagiri words

Tags: visualforce

I am using Arial Unicode MS font in the html. I need to render it as pdf. 
The html contains Devnagari words. HTML is displayed properly but the words are broken in the generated pdf. e.g "आपल्या" => आपल् या
Has anybody faced this problem? Any pointers will help

Comment: I had to download the most recent version of Adobe Reader to get Japanese characters to work, which may be a similar situation. Do you have the most recent version of [Adobe Reader](http://get.adobe.com/reader/)?

Comment: @user3315 Was your issue ever resolved? We are facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, Salesforce fully supports Hindi. I understand Devanagari is the Sanskrit alphabet used for Standard Hindi. I'd expect the font to be in SF's cache when they produce the PDF so all the glyphs needed (including ligatures) will be there for it to render properly. Have you checked the PDF document to see if they were embedded in it?

Its possible the SF PDF generator may not "understand" the rules of the Hindi language, thus breaking apart words as it did in your example. In the latter case, I think you probably need to look at adding "Unforced Breaks" code to your CSS to the HTML you're using that helps prevent any words from being hyphenated or inadvertently broken up by the PDF generator. The [W3 CSS Fragmentation Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-break/#break-properties) covers those properties and will hopefully help you figure out how to implement a solution that will solve the issue you're having.